# Why does the AJAX call get 0 but the PHP function work properly?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, while-loop

I've created a function into my functions.php that is working absolutely fine when I call it into my template files in PHP but when I try to execute this same function via AJAX, instead of throwing what it should I get a "0" value. I'm clearly missing something here... But what?

I already tried to remove everything from my PHP function in order to echo a  dummy value and it is working fine. So the function/call names shouldn't be the problem. The issue happen when I put my loop and variables back, thing is is that I'm really trying to not "echo" each HTML line of my templates files as it would be a total mess.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_js_mosaic', 'my_mosaic');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_js_mosaic', 'my_mosaic');

function my_mosaic() { //When I execute it into my templates, everything is fine!

        $offset = $_POST['offset'];
        $post_per_page = 9;
        $index = 0;
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

        if(wp_is_mobile()) {
          $post_per_page = 5;
        }

        if($offset != 0){
            $query_articles = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page'=>$post_per_page,
            'paged' => $paged,
                'offset' => $offset
          );
        } else {
            $query_articles = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page'=>$post_per_page,
            'paged' => $paged
          );
        }

            $articles = new WP_Query( $query_articles );

            if( have_posts() ) :
                echo '<div id="mosaic" class="col-md-8 offset-md-1 row no-gutters wrapper-illustrations">';
                    while ( $articles->have_posts() ) :
                            $articles->the_post();
                            $index++;
                            set_query_var( 'articles', $articles );
                            set_query_var( 'index', $index );

                            // get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'mosaic' ); //works well too
                            include( 'template-parts/content-mosaic.php' );

                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    echo '</div>';
                    // get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'navigation' ); //works well too
                    include( 'template-parts/content-navigation.php' );
            endif;
}
```

The jQuery call :

```
  function load_mosaic(offset) {

    var data = {
      action: 'js_mosaic',
      offset: offset
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
      console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
      //$('#mosaic').html(response); //Not good div, I know
    });
  }
  load_mosaic();
```

I just wanted this ajax call to execute as it should...

Comment: Well I respond to myself the problem was at the ' if( have_posts() ) :' line, removing it with the correpsonding endif, make the ajax work

Comment: It's also a good practice to use die() at the end of functions you call with ajax.  Not using can lead to issues.

Comment: kill your request, either use ```wp_send_json()``` or put your whole "echo" element into a variable and assign it on ```die( $element )``` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_js_mosaic', 'my_mosaic');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_js_mosaic', 'my_mosaic');

function my_mosaic() { //When I execute it into my templates, everything is fine!

    $offset = $_POST['offset'];
    $post_per_page = 9;
    $index = 0;
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    if(wp_is_mobile()) {
      $post_per_page = 5;
    }

    if($offset != 0){
        $query_articles = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>$post_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'offset' => $offset
      );
    } else {
        $query_articles = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>$post_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged
      );
    }

    $articles = new WP_Query( $query_articles );

    if( have_posts() ) :
        $return = '<div id="mosaic" class="col-md-8 offset-md-1 row no-gutters wrapper-illustrations">';
            while ( $articles->have_posts() ) :
                $articles->the_post();
                $index++;
                set_query_var( 'articles', $articles );
                set_query_var( 'index', $index );
                $return .= get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'mosaic' );

            endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $return .= '</div>';
        $return .= get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'navigation' ); 
    endif;
    return $return;
}
```